# featuretools historical label counts

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, featuretools

### Background

For a CRM project, I have snapshots of opportunities. I've been able to build many features w/ `featuretools` already, but what I really want is to have historical win counts and rate. In other terms, I'd like to know:

> For a given opportunity, how many deals have been won up until the opportunity was last modified?

### Example Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'OpportunityId': [111, 111, 222, 222, 222, 333, 333, 333],
     'UpdateId': [1,3,2,5,7,4,6,8],
     'Label': ['Open', 'Win', 'Open', 'Open', 'Win', 'Open', 'Open', 'Open'],
     'CreatedOn': pd.to_datetime(['9/27/18','9/27/18','9/28/18','9/28/18','9/28/18','10/2/18','10/2/18','10/2/18']),
     'ModifiedOn': pd.to_datetime(['9/27/18','10/1/18','9/28/18','10/3/18','10/7/18','10/2/18','10/6/18','10/10/18']),
     'EstRevenue': [2000, 2000, 80000, 84000, 78000, 100000, 95000, 110000]})
df
```

```
| OpportunityId | UpdateId | Label | CreatedOn  | ModifiedOn | EstRevenue |
|---------------|----------|-------|------------|------------|------------|
| 111           | 1        | Open  | 2018-09-27 | 2018-09-27 | 2000       |
| 111           | 3        | Win   | 2018-09-27 | 2018-10-01 | 2000       |
| 222           | 2        | Open  | 2018-09-28 | 2018-09-28 | 80000      |
| 222           | 5        | Open  | 2018-09-28 | 2018-10-03 | 84000      |
| 222           | 7        | Win   | 2018-09-28 | 2018-10-07 | 78000      |
| 333           | 4        | Open  | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-02 | 100000     |
| 333           | 6        | Open  | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-06 | 95000      |
| 333           | 8        | Open  | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-10 | 110000     |
```

### Desired Output

```
| OPPORTUNITIES | Label | CreatedOn | Max( ModifiedOn ) | AVG( EstRevenue ) | Wins |
|---------------|-------|-----------|-------------------|------------------:|------|
| 111           | Win   | 9/27/18   | 10/1/18           |              2000 | 0    |
| 222           | Win   | 9/28/18   | 10/7/18           |             80667 | 1    |
| 333           | Open  | 10/2/18   | 10/10/18          |            101667 | 2    |
```

### Attempts so far

What is hard for me to wrap my brain around is...

1. Features that are dependent on multiple opportunities... do I need a separate entity?
2. How do I aggregate the `Label` that delivers both:

   1. The current value of the `Label`, and
   2. The count when the `Label` column is 0

The challenge for me is the `Label` column... Whereas normally I would make a `CurrentLabel` column, I'm pretty sure `ft` can handle this...

```
es = (ft.EntitySet(id='CRM')
      .entity_from_dataframe(
          entity_id='updates',
          dataframe=df,
          index='UpdateId',
          time_index='ModifiedOn')
      .normalize_entity(
          base_entity_id='updates',
          new_entity_id='opportunities',
          index='OpportunityId',
          make_time_index='CreatedOn',
          copy_variables=['Label'],
          additional_variables=['CreatedOn']
      )
)
es['updates']['Label'].interesting_values  = ['Win']
```

```
Entityset: CRM
  Entities:
    updates [Rows: 8, Columns: 5]
    opportunities [Rows: 3, Columns: 3]
  Relationships:
    updates.OpportunityId -> opportunities.OpportunityId
```

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity="opportunities",
    agg_primitives=[
        "mean","count","num_unique","time_since_first"],
    trans_primitives=[
        'time_since_previous'],
    where_primitives=[
        "sum","count"],
    max_depth=2,
    verbose=1
)
```

Comment: what is the logic for aggregated results in columns `'Wins'` and `'Label'`? I understand the other columns, but not these ones.

Comment: `Label` is whether the opportunity was 'Won' or 'Lost', which I'm trying to predict. `Wins` column is the answer to the question:  how many deals have been won up until the opportunity was last modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different ways you could tackle this problem:

1. **Create a new dataframe column and use the `last` aggregation primitive**

For this approach, before you create your entityset, first create a new `Wins` column in your dataframe that tracks the cumulative total of wins over time. You may need to sort your dataframe by the `ModifiedOn` column to make sure the cumulative sum value is correct. Also, I am using `.shift()` here to shift the column values by one position, to only count the wins that occurred *before* the update:

```
df = df.sort_values('ModifiedOn')
df['Wins'] = df['Label'].shift().eq('Win').cumsum()
```

When you run deep feature synthesis, add the `last` primitive to your list of `agg_primitives`:

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity="opportunities",
    agg_primitives=["mean", "count", "num_unique", "time_since_first", "last"],
    trans_primitives=["time_since_previous"],
    where_primitives=["sum", "count"],
    max_depth=2,
    verbose=1
)
```

Now, when you inspect your feature matrix you will have a column labeled `LAST(updates.Label)` that displays the value for `Label` at the time the opportunity was last updated. You will also have a column labeled `LAST(updates.Wins)` that displays the total wins at the time the opportunity was last updated.

2. **Use a seed feature with a custom primitive**
   This approach is conceptually similar as the first approach, but utilizes a seed feature and a custom primitive to arrive at the desired output.

Before you run deep feature synthesis, create a new boolean seed feature that defines whether the `Label` is equal to `Win`:

```
label_is_win = ft.Feature(es["updates"]["Label"]) == "Win"
```

Next, define a custom transform primitive that will use this seed feature to return the cumulative sum of wins:

```
class ShiftedCumSumBoolean(ft.primitives.TransformPrimitive):
    name = "shifted_cum_sum_boolean"
    input_types = [ft.variable_types.Boolean]
    return_type = ft.variable_types.Numeric
    uses_full_entity = True

    def get_function(self):
        def shifted_cum_sum(values):
            return values.shift(fill_value=(False)).cumsum()

        return shifted_cum_sum
```

When you run deep feature synthesis, add the new `ShiftedCumSumBoolean` primitive to the list of `trans_primitives`. Also, add the `last` primitive to the list of `agg_primitives` to provide the last label value when the opportunity was updated. Finally, add the `label_is_win` seed feature to the list of seed features in the `ft.dfs` call:

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity="opportunities",
    agg_primitives=["mean","count","num_unique","time_since_first", "last"],
    trans_primitives=["time_since_previous", ShiftedCumSumBoolean],
    where_primitives=["sum", "count"],
    seed_features=[label_is_win],
    max_depth=2,
    verbose=1,
)
```

With this solution your feature matrix will have a column labeled `LAST(updates.Label)` that displays the value for `Label` at the time the opportunity was last updated. You will also have a column labeled `LAST(updates.SHIFTED_CUM_SUM_BOOLEAN(Label = Win))` that displays the total wins at the time the opportunity was last updated.